# Factored Quadratic Expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Given the polynomial $x^2+7x+12$ which can be factored as $(x+3)(x+4)$. Can $(x+3)(x+4)$ be defined in a way other than as a factored(ised) expression or does it have an algebraic name or fall within the ambit of any other definition?

Comment: You can apply completing the squares. It results in $f(x)=(x+3.5)^2-\frac14$ With this form of a quadratic function you can read off the apex or you can derive the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

While the question is not very clear to me, I guess you are asking about ways to write a polynomial. Yes, there are different ways - Choosing a specific form depends on what do you want to do next with it.

let: $$f(x)=x^{2}+7x+12$$

(1) using factorization as you did:
$$f(x)=(x+3)(x+4)$$

(2) re-arranging factors:
$$f(x)=(x+3)^2+(x+3)$$

(3) Using Horner's Method (used to speed calculation by reducing number of arithmetic operations):
$$f(x)=x\left(7+x\right)+12$$

(4) Using an Integral Form (where C is any constant):
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{7x^2}{2}+12x+C)$$

(5) Using Taylor Series around a value v:

$$\left(v^2+7v+12\right)+\left(2v+7\right)\left(x-v\right)+\left(x-v\right)^2\ $$

(6) Generic representation of a polynomial is:
$$f\left(x\right)=\sum _{n=0}^2\:\:\left(a_k\:\:x^k\right)$$
Where: $a_k=\{1,7,12\}$